# camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter-webapp dependency not working and embedded tomcat failing

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, business-process-management, camunda

I am trying to create a simple camunda spring boot starter webapp based on examples given here https://github.com/osteinhauer/camunda-spring-boot-starter-examples . My main application class has just this simple piece of code :

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class StartApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
SpringApplication.run(StartApp.class, args);
    }

}
```

My pom.xml looks something like this below :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>info.quarrymen.camunda-spring-boot-starter-examples</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <artifactId>quick-start-webapp</artifactId>

  <dependencies>
  <dependency>
  <groupId>org.camunda.bpm.extension.springboot</groupId>
  <artifactId>camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.camunda.bpm.extension.springboot</groupId>
      <artifactId>camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter-webapp</artifactId>
      <version>${camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

But my embedded tomcat fails to start with below error :

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) [na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192) [na:1.8.0_144]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:939) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_144]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/camunda/bpm/welcome/impl/web/bootstrap/WelcomeContainerBootstrap
    at org.camunda.bpm.spring.boot.starter.webapp.CamundaBpmWebappInitializer.onStartup(CamundaBpmWebappInitializer.java:59) ~[camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter-webapp-core-2.1.2.jar:2.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.selfInitialize(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:229) ~[spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.access$000(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:89) ~[spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext$1.onStartup(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:213) ~[spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter.onStartup(TomcatStarter.java:55) ~[spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5196) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.camunda.bpm.welcome.impl.web.bootstrap.WelcomeContainerBootstrap
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    ... 13 common frames omitted

2017-08-21 00:17:25.140 ERROR 5956 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase   : A child container failed during start

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:939) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:793) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:344) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:99) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.<init>(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:84) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:554) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:179) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:164) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:134) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537) [spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at info.quarrymen.quickstart.webapp.Application.main(Application.java:19) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:947) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    ... 6 common frames omitted

2017-08-21 00:17:25.141  WARN 5956 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
2017-08-21 00:17:25.152  INFO 5956 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2017-08-21 00:17:25.158 ERROR 5956 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:137) ~[spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537) ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at info.quarrymen.quickstart.webapp.Application.main(Application.java:19) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:123) ~[spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.<init>(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:84) ~[spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:554) ~[spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:179) ~[spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:164) ~[spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:134) ~[spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[-1]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:344) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:99) ~[spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    ... 13 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Tomcat]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:793) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    ... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:947) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
```

Looks like only adding `camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter-webapp` won't help . Some additional configuration is required . I tried many combinations of maven dependencies , but it didn't work out . Anyone who has faced the similar issue , please help or let know the correct set of dependencies so that i can run camunda webapp on localhost with spring boot . Thanks in advance .

@Daniel ,after trying your pom.xml , i am getting below errors . They are different from previous errors :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot instantiate interface org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener : org.camunda.bpm.spring.boot.starter.runlistener.PropertiesListener
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:413)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:392)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:383)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.initialize(SpringApplication.java:251)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>(SpringApplication.java:225)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
    at org.camundastarter.MainApp.main(MainApp.java:11)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.camunda.bpm.spring.boot.starter.runlistener.PropertiesListener]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/camunda/bpm/engine/ProcessEngine
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:154)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:409)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/camunda/bpm/engine/ProcessEngine
    at org.camunda.bpm.spring.boot.starter.util.CamundaBpmVersion.<init>(CamundaBpmVersion.java:36)
    at org.camunda.bpm.spring.boot.starter.runlistener.PropertiesListener.<init>(PropertiesListener.java:20)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:142)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.camunda.bpm.engine.ProcessEngine
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 15 more
```

@Daniel ... ERRORS AGAIN AFTER CLEANING MAVEN DIRECTORY  !! :(

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot instantiate interface org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener : org.camunda.bpm.spring.boot.starter.runlistener.PropertiesListener
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:413)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:392)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:383)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.initialize(SpringApplication.java:251)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>(SpringApplication.java:225)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
    at org.camundastarter.MainApp.main(MainApp.java:11)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.camunda.bpm.spring.boot.starter.runlistener.PropertiesListener]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/camunda/bpm/engine/ProcessEngine
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:154)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:409)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/camunda/bpm/engine/ProcessEngine
    at org.camunda.bpm.spring.boot.starter.util.CamundaBpmVersion.<init>(CamundaBpmVersion.java:36)
    at org.camunda.bpm.spring.boot.starter.runlistener.PropertiesListener.<init>(PropertiesListener.java:20)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:142)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.camunda.bpm.engine.ProcessEngine
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 15 more
```

Comment: Please remove the need for a parent and post the full pom.xml here, that makes it easier to help. I also think you should delete the "camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter" depency, will be added transitively - currently you might get version conflicts because you use "2.3.0-SNAPSHOT"

Comment: Hi Bern thanks for your time to reply, this is my full pom.xml . It is just a small sample project . Are you asking me to post effective pom.xml here ? Should i not use snapshot , then how should i make it work .

Comment: you should stick to the "official" examples in the spring boot starter repo, I suppose olivers might not be up top date. Also, if you just want to use the extension, don't try the snapshot version, stick to the latest release (2.2.0 in this case)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just set the property for `camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter.version` on your pom.xml file like this.

```
 <properties>
    <camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter.version>2.1.2</camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter.version>
</properties>
```

And then \import the camunda dependencies again through maven, and try to start the app again.

This is the output that I get from spring boot when camunda is started

```
 ____                                 _         ____  ____  __  __
/ ___| __ _ _ __ ___  _   _ _ __   __| | __ _  | __ )|  _ \|  \/  |
| |   / _` | '_ ` _ \| | | | '_ \ / _` |/ _` | |  _ \| |_) | |\/| |
| |__| (_| | | | | | | |_| | | | | (_| | (_| | | |_) |  __/| |  | |
\____/\__,_|_| |_| |_|\__,_|_| |_|\__,_|\__,_| |____/|_|   |_|  |_|

  Spring-Boot:  (v1.5.6.RELEASE)
  Camunda BPM: (v7.6.0)
  Camunda BPM Spring Boot Starter: (v2.1.2)

2017-08-20 16:17:40.653  INFO 2690 --- [           main] c.c.s.d.DemoCamundaApplication           : Starting DemoCamundaApplication on ultronE460 with PID 2690 (/home/ultron/Documents/projects/demo-camunda/target/classes started by ultron in /home/ultron/Documents/projects/demo-camunda)
2017-08-20 16:17:40.667  INFO 2690 --- [           main] c.c.s.d.DemoCamundaApplication           : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-08-20 16:17:40.890  INFO 2690 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@1d548a08: startup date [Sun Aug 20 16:17:40 EST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-08-20 16:17:41.689  INFO 2690 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'dataSource' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Dbcp; factoryMethodName=dataSource; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Dbcp.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat; factoryMethodName=dataSource; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat.class]]
2017-08-20 16:17:42.629  INFO 2690 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-08-20 16:17:42.638  INFO 2690 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2017-08-20 16:17:42.639  INFO 2690 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.16
2017-08-20 16:17:42.774  INFO 2690 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2017-08-20 16:17:42.775  INFO 2690 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1895 ms
2017-08-20 16:17:42.894  INFO 2690 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2017-08-20 16:17:42.900  INFO 2690 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2017-08-20 16:17:42.900  INFO 2690 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2017-08-20 16:17:42.901  INFO 2690 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2017-08-20 16:17:42.901  INFO 2690 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2017-08-20 16:17:43.355  INFO 2690 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-08-20 16:17:43.367  INFO 2690 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2017-08-20 16:17:43.437  INFO 2690 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.12.Final}
2017-08-20 16:17:43.439  INFO 2690 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2017-08-20 16:17:43.441  INFO 2690 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2017-08-20 16:17:43.496  INFO 2690 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2017-08-20 16:17:43.605  INFO 2690 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
2017-08-20 16:17:43.810  INFO 2690 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
2017-08-20 16:17:43.816  INFO 2690 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000230: Schema export complete
2017-08-20 16:17:43.831  INFO 2690 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-08-20 16:17:44.259  INFO 2690 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@1d548a08: startup date [Sun Aug 20 16:17:40 EST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-08-20 16:17:44.327  INFO 2690 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2017-08-20 16:17:44.327  INFO 2690 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2017-08-20 16:17:44.357  INFO 2690 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-08-20 16:17:44.357  INFO 2690 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-08-20 16:17:44.390  INFO 2690 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-08-20 16:17:44.545  INFO 2690 --- [           main] org.camunda.bpm.spring.boot              : STARTER-SB040 Setting up jobExecutor with pool-size 1
2017-08-20 16:17:44.551  INFO 2690 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService  'camundaTaskExecutor'
2017-08-20 16:17:44.681  INFO 2690 --- [           main] org.camunda.bpm.engine.cfg               : ENGINE-12003 Plugin 'CompositeProcessEnginePlugin[genericPropertiesConfiguration, camundaProcessEngineConfiguration, camundaDatasourceConfiguration, camundaJpaConfiguration, camundaJobConfiguration, camundaHistoryConfiguration, camundaMetricsConfiguration, camundaAuthorizationConfiguration, camundaDeploymentConfiguration, failedJobConfiguration]' activated on process engine 'default'
2017-08-20 16:17:46.087  INFO 2690 --- [           main] org.camunda.bpm.spring.boot              : STARTER-SB021 Auto-Deploying resources: []
2017-08-20 16:17:48.591  INFO 2690 --- [           main] org.camunda.bpm.engine.persistence       : ENGINE-03016 Performing database operation 'create' on component 'engine' with resource 'org/camunda/bpm/engine/db/create/activiti.h2.create.engine.sql'
2017-08-20 16:17:48.611  INFO 2690 --- [           main] org.camunda.bpm.engine.persistence       : ENGINE-03016 Performing database operation 'create' on component 'history' with resource 'org/camunda/bpm/engine/db/create/activiti.h2.create.history.sql'
2017-08-20 16:17:48.623  INFO 2690 --- [           main] org.camunda.bpm.engine.persistence       : ENGINE-03016 Performing database operation 'create' on component 'identity' with resource 'org/camunda/bpm/engine/db/create/activiti.h2.create.identity.sql'
2017-08-20 16:17:48.638  INFO 2690 --- [           main] org.camunda.bpm.engine.persistence       : ENGINE-03016 Performing database operation 'create' on component 'case.engine' with resource 'org/camunda/bpm/engine/db/create/activiti.h2.create.case.engine.sql'
2017-08-20 16:17:48.644  INFO 2690 --- [           main] org.camunda.bpm.engine.persistence       : ENGINE-03016 Performing database operation 'create' on component 'case.history' with resource 'org/camunda/bpm/engine/db/create/activiti.h2.create.case.history.sql'
2017-08-20 16:17:48.649  INFO 2690 --- [           main] org.camunda.bpm.engine.persistence       : ENGINE-03016 Performing database operation 'create' on component 'decision.engine' with resource 'org/camunda/bpm/engine/db/create/activiti.h2.create.decision.engine.sql'
2017-08-20 16:17:48.656  INFO 2690 --- [           main] org.camunda.bpm.engine.persistence       : ENGINE-03016 Performing database operation 'create' on component 'decision.history' with resource 'org/camunda/bpm/engine/db/create/activiti.h2.create.decision.history.sql'
2017-08-20 16:17:48.670  INFO 2690 --- [           main] org.camunda.bpm.engine.persistence       : ENGINE-03067 No history level property found in database
2017-08-20 16:17:48.671  INFO 2690 --- [           main] org.camunda.bpm.engine.persistence       : ENGINE-03065 Creating historyLevel property in database for level: HistoryLevelAudit(name=audit, id=2)
2017-08-20 16:17:48.678  INFO 2690 --- [           main] org.camunda.bpm.engine                   : ENGINE-00001 Process Engine default created.
2017-08-20 16:17:49.024  INFO 2690 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2017-08-20 16:17:49.080  INFO 2690 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-08-20 16:17:49.086  INFO 2690 --- [           main] org.camunda.bpm.engine.jobexecutor       : ENGINE-14014 Starting up the JobExecutor[org.camunda.bpm.engine.spring.components.jobexecutor.SpringJobExecutor].
2017-08-20 16:17:49.088  INFO 2690 --- [ingJobExecutor]] org.camunda.bpm.engine.jobexecutor       : ENGINE-14018 JobExecutor[org.camunda.bpm.engine.spring.components.jobexecutor.SpringJobExecutor] starting to acquire jobs
2017-08-20 16:17:49.089  INFO 2690 --- [           main] c.c.s.d.DemoCamundaApplication           : Started DemoCamundaApplication in 9.431 seconds (JVM running for 10.825)
2017-08-20 16:18:09.162  INFO 2690 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2017-08-20 16:18:09.162  INFO 2690 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2017-08-20 16:18:09.178  INFO 2690 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 16 ms
```

And this is the following pom.xml that I used, I haven't create any bpmn workflow, just add the dependencies, but I thing is a good start in order to create the workflows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.camunda.sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo-camunda</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo-camunda</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter.version>2.1.2</camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter.version>
    </properties>



    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.camunda.bpm.extension.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>camunda-extensions-nexus</id>
            <url>https://app.camunda.com/nexus/content/repositories/camunda-bpm-community-extensions-snapshots</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

**Only for Eclipse users: after pom.xml has been changed do this:**

[image: How to update maven project after pom.xml has been changed]

Comment: I tried what you told . But still facing the same nagging issue :( .

Comment: do you have any pom.xml combination for above issue that works for you ?

Comment: i tried what you told but still getting below errors

Comment: In that case maybe there is a problem with your maven local repo if you are using eclipse right click to the project select maven and update maven dependencies.  Also you can clean up all your local maven repo and try to reload them.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply first !!! i deleted all folders from my repository folder , and then built the project again but still the errors persist , is something buggy with my eclipse ? I will paste the errors in updated question .

Comment: ok. some additional steps after build the project.  try this right click to your eclipse project —> select the option calle Maven —> it will list other sub menu list at that point select update dependencies

Comment: and build again

Comment: I just add a picture of how Update project after pom.xml changing, try this and build again, it should work, in my case I try it with Eclipse Oxygen an works perfect!

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at this project,
https://github.com/berndruecker/camunda-spring-boot-amqp-microservice-cloud-example

Here is the sample pom.xml for reference,
https://github.com/berndruecker/camunda-spring-boot-amqp-microservice-cloud-example/blob/master/pom.xml